# Comment does not hint detail in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments

I have a method in **Interface** like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create File 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="f">Files object</param>
    /// <returns>True if success, else return false</returns>
    bool Create(Entities.Files f);
```

The problem when I call this method, visual studio just hint the String "Create File". I don't know why it does not show the String in param and return
[image]

Also I try to put this comment into class that implements interface, it does not work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliSense does not show the contents of the `<returns>` section, and it only shows the contents of a `<param>` section after you have "reached" the position of that parameter in your expression, e.g. you need to first type `p.Create(` to see it. That's just how it works.

Answer (score 2):

the string in `param`  and `returns` will only show up once you get to the opening parenthesis and depending on the current param its type and description will be shown, that's how intellisense works.

Answer (score 2):

That just can't work well, falls down on a method with a lot of arguments or when a method has overloads. Just keep going to get:

[image]

Feature, not a bug.